# AJAX request not working in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

```
$('.sizeSelect').change(function(size) {
sizeId = $(this).attr('id');
size = $('#' + sizeId).val();
lastChar = sizeId.substr(5);
addBtn = "#btn_" + lastChar;
shipId = "shipping_" + lastChar;

if (size=="")
 {
   document.getElementById(shipId).innerHTML="";
   return;
 } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   document.getElementById(shipId).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    if (response == 0.00) {
        $(addBtn).addClass('invisible');
    }
    else if (response > 0.00) {
        $(addBtn).removeClass('invisible');
    }
}
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","cart.php?size="+size+"&shipId="+lastChar, true);
xmlhttp.send();

 });
```

Can anyone tell me why this works in Chrome, Firefox and safari and not in IE. I read somewhere that it had to do with forcing ie not to cache and that changing the the request from a get to a post would help... it didnt :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to 2012...there's no excuse for writing javascript like this anymore.

Comment: @blockhead that's not very constructive. I often write vanilla code to learn how something works. Or else all you are is a jQuery (/ whatever else) dev.

Comment: @Marshall Some of us, need to earn a living as well. The code here doesn't look like an attempt "just to see if something works"...it looks like attempted production code.

Comment: Regardless of the purpose my question concerned the functionality and your answer did not address that. What would you do? I want to do things in a way that works, so please enlighten me :)

Comment: @blockhead I make a living writing JavaScript. And I have gained a lot by writing code from scratch. It has helped more than I can say, when I've needed to modify libraries / modules directly. And you misquoted me by prepending a "Just to."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using jQuery? Have you checked how IE is handling the response - perhaps it sees "0.00" as text you have to parseFloat?

Comment: I am using a jquery .ajax elswhere, but had some trouble getting it to work for this. I would prefer to use the jquery .ajax method.

Comment: I wanted encapsulate on the called page the code that places the content on the calling page but I started having trouble with FireFox also not putting the content in the target <div>. I ended up making sure any content moving functionality I needed was already present in the parent page

`<script src="my.js"></script>`

works fine in IE and again FF

Answer (score 0):

the trick is use separate code XML for IE browsers or that are version of less than 10 .

so every time Ajax is call a method parseXml is called with input parameter XML Dom or text, depending on browser .... and if current browser is IE, it upload XML doc, process it according to Microsoft standards and return XML and rest of processes in Ajax carries on as expected!!

note : browser.msie is not supported in jQuery 1.9 but you can add jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js in order to make it compatible or use userAgent and find which is current browser

```
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'XML_file.xml',
  dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
  success: function (xml) {

     var processedXML = parseXml(xml);

     $(processedXML).find('my record').each(function () {  //code  } 
   });


 function parseXml(xml) {

 if ($.browser.msie)  {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "XML_file.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    xml = xmlDoc;
 }
   return xml;
}
```